# Kakfa Streams multiple applications / streams on same node?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Hopefully this is a quick and easy question. Right now I have an application that has two unique tasks on it in the same stream. When the entire application runs, partitions are not balanced across the two tasks which was an issue as one of the tasks requires more resources (memory / cpu)

In order to solve this I created two unique streams with different stream builders in my application and started them separately. By setting it up this way, the partitions were balanced in the way I expected.

```
kafkaStreams0 = new KafkaStreams(kafkaStreamsBuilder0.build(), streamsProperties0)
kafkaStreams1 = new KafkaStreams(kafkaStreamsBuilder1.build(), streamsProperties1)

kafkaStreams0.start()
kafkaStreams1.start()
```

I'm giving each of these their own application id in the stream properties. Something about this seems like a hack, but I can't find any documentation about whether this is a valid solution.

As a note: I'd like to avoid splitting these into two applications as I don't want to add the operational overhead.

Comment: Can you give more details? What kind of balancing do you expected and what inbalancing did you get originally? What's the application.id setting for both? Do both builder express the same or different program?

Comment: Basically I was having a situation where task 0 was getting more partitions than task 1 was getting. When 0 got more than 1 it causes imbalanced resources across many nodes.

It also wasn't consistent across nodes how many partitions 0 got vs 1.